# -bash: ./jdk-6u31-linux-i586.bin: cannot execute binary file

Tags: java, linux

I installed `JDK` on `Linux`. There is a problem that says:

```
-bash: ./jdk-6u31-linux-i586.bin: cannot execute binary file.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: @jjmartinez NO! That won't solve anything, quite the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if `jdk-6u31-linux-i586.bin` weren't in a binary format which is runnable by your computer. Some of the possible causes:

- you are on a non-ix86-compatible Computer (f.e., on an arm)
- you are on an x64 Computer, but i386-compatibility isn't turned on.
- your download of this binary is somehow failed and this binary file is broken.

The last has far the greatest possibility!

What you get for a

```
file jdk-6u31-linux-i586.bin
```

command? If it is not some about "elf 32 bit image" or like, you should download this again.